# Why plus operator in Java always produces Integer?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jvm, language-specifications

I have code like this

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2 ;
short c = a + b; // dosen't compile
```

What is the reason for compilation failure? `x` + `x` always produces `Integer` or *bigger* `Number`, but why?

Comment: Because the language designers decided thusly. Would you like a quote from the JLS with that?

Comment: I have heard that this is NOT specified in JLS.

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100785/short-plus-short-is-an-int and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java

Comment: @MariuszS It is : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Comment: The important point is : an int can't be cast into a short. Addition of a and b will produce int. Then, since it can't be cast into short will throw compilation error.

Comment: *When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type (...) Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

None of the binary operators will produce an `Integer`.  However, it will use an `int` instead of shorter types, `byte`, `short` and `char`  If the compiler can inline the value it can cast the value for your. e.g.

```
final short a = 1;
final short b = 2;
short c = a + b; // does compile, because of constant inlining.
```

The only operator which produces an `Integer` is a cast.

```
Integer i = (Integer) 1;
```

BTW: On oddity is that Java defines the 32-bit `float` as being "wider" than the 64-bit `long` value.  This has the downside that float has much less precision.  Consider this.

```
long l = 7777777777777777777L;
l += 0.0f;
System.out.println(l);
```

prints

```
7777777579364188160
```

Even though 0.0F was added to `l` it was implicitly cast to `float` (as float is wider) and then cast back (as an operator assignment was used) resulting in a error of ~20 billion.

Comment: +1: Learned something today :)

Comment: Possibly a dummy question for @PeterLawrey, but what does actually "to inline the value" mean ?

Comment: @kocko `a` and `b` are *compile-time constants* and wherever they are used in the code, their *value* is compiled in. The bytecode contains no trace of the fact that the source code actually had variables holding the values.

Comment: @kocko it means the compiler puts the value in the code as if you had typed it there i.e. the byte code will read `short c = 3;`  This generally doesn't matter much but if you change a constant using reflection it could mean it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you both for your simple and clear clarifications :)

Comment: Thanks for `final` example :)

Comment: Of course `float`s are “wider” than `long`s; you can get much larger values in a `float` (all the way up to `+Inf`…). It just has less precision; its a potentially lossy conversion (in _both_ directions). OTOH, everything in `int` fits exactly in a `double`…